# Gmail API - Download attachments from new mails required SCOPES - JAVA

Tags: java, email, gmail-api

I work on app that download attachments from new messages using **GMAIL API**. I already made app with **JavaMail** but have to avoid using **IMAP** protocol.

I successfully logged into mail account with **Oauth2**, but now I need help with fetching new mails and downloading attachments.
I saw example code where we search for messages by ID but its not usable in this situation.

**EDIT 1 :**
Code that I have is same as code from, just separated in classes [Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/java)

**EDIT 2:**

```
    String user = "me";
    ListMessagesResponse listMessageResponse = service.users().messages().list(user).setQ("is:unseen").execute();
    List<Message> list = listMessageResponse.getMessages();
    for(Message m : list) {
        List<MessagePart> part = m.getPayload().getParts();
        for(MessagePart p: part) {
            if(p.getFilename()!=null && p.getFilename().length()>0) {
                System.out.println(p.getFilename());
            }
        }
    }
```

I get error for this line

```
ListMessagesResponse listMessageResponse = service.users().messages().list(user).setQ("is:unseen").execute();


Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Insufficient Permission",
    "reason" : "insufficientPermissions"
  } ],
  "message" : "Insufficient Permission"
}
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:150)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:451)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1089)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:549)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:482)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:599)
    at Main.main(Main.java:64)
```

**EDIT 3:**

Made `SCOPES` working with replacing `GMAIL_LABELS` with `GMAIL_READONLY`, I think I successfully fetched unseen mails, now I have somehow to download attachments.

```
ListMessagesResponse listMessageResponse = service.users().messages().list(user).setQ("is:unseen").execute();
```

`listMessageresponse` is not `null`, while `list` equals `null`

```
List<Message> list = listMessageResponse.getMessages();
```

Comment: Please provide the code you have so far.

Comment: You can [list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list) your emails specifying with the `q` parameter `is:unread` to fetch the new messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a permission issue (as stated by the exception). Permissions can be obtained by requesting a SCOPE when authenticating.
If you are using the sample from the quickstart, you will see they are using the `GMAIL_LABELS` scope:

```
private static final List<String> SCOPES = Collections.singletonList(GmailScopes.GMAIL_LABELS);
```

To get the email content you need to add more scopes, i.e. `GMAIL_READONLY` or others scope allowing to access emails (see [GmailScopes](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/gmail/v1/java/latest/com/google/api/services/gmail/GmailScopes.html)).

Depending on how you create your credentials/token you might not be allowed to these scopes (then just update your settings in your API settings for the proper scopes)

Comment: Thanks, made `SCOPES` changes and it finally worked. I think that I fetched unseen mails successfully, but still have somehow to get attachments and download them.

Comment: Great. If you consider the question answered, please accept it.

Comment: Done. Sorry, new here so I didn't know about that feature.

Comment: Do you have any idea for rest of problems (this resolved only scopes issues)?